# Can I fetch my desired data in one LINQ-to-entities call?

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I need a little help in figuring out how I can fetch the location name of the student's home in the below scenario. These are entity framework entities.

```cs
class Attendance
{
  int Id;
  DateTime AttendanceDate;
  bool IsPresent;
  Student Student;
  Location Location;
}

class Student
{
  int Id;
  string Name;
  string HomeLocationCode;
}

class Location
{
  int Id;
  string LocationCode;
  string Name;
}
```

I have the below working C# code, but it fetches home location code, not name:

```cs
var attendances = await _dbContext.Attendances.Select(x => new QueryResult
{
    Id = x.Id,
    AttendanceDate = x.AttendanceDate,
    IsPresent = x.IsPresent,
    AttendanceLocationCode = x.Location.LocationCode,
    AttendanceLocationName = x.Location.LocationName,
    HomeLocation = x.Student.LocationCode, // I want name instead of code here
}, cancellationToken);
```

Also, I have the working SQL query, in case that helps:

```sql
SELECT c.Id, c.AttendanceDate, c.Name, c.LastName, c.StudentId, m.LocationName AS AttendanceLocation, s.LocationCode AS HomeLocation
FROM [Attednace] AS c
LEFT JOIN [Student] AS s ON c.Id = s.Id
INNER JOIN [Location] AS m ON c.Id = m.Id
```

I want to modify the above written c# LINQ-to-entities code to fetch student's home location name if `Attendance.Student` field is not null. I can do this in two separate SQL calls but I don't want to. Note that `HomeLocation` is not a foreign key to `Location`.

As mentioned above, the two separate SQL calls solution is written below.

```cs
// The 1st database call which fetches everything but
var attendances = await _dbContext.Attendances.Select(x => new QueryResult
{
    Id = x.Id,
    AttendanceDate = x.AttendanceDate,
    IsPresent = x.IsPresent,
    AttendanceLocationCode = x.Location.LocationCode,
    AttendanceLocationName = x.Location.LocationName,
    HomeLocation = x.Student.LocationCode, // temporary assignment
}, cancellationToken);

// The 2nd database call
var locations = await _dbContext.Locations
    .Where(x => attendances.Select(c => c.HomeLocation).Distinct().Contains(x.LocationCode))
    .ListAsync();

foreach (var item in attendances)
{
    item.HomeLocation = locations
        .Where(l => l.LocationCode == item.HomeLocation)
        .Select(l => l.Name)
        .SingleOrDefault();
}

// At this point the 'HomeLocation' property in all the list items is correctly populated.
```

My goal is to somehow convert these two database calls in one database call.

Comment: What prevents you from using `x.Student.Name`?

Comment: something like this ?  `StudentName =  x.Student != null ? x.Student.Name : string.empty`

Comment: @GertArnold thank you for pointing out the mistake. I have updated the question code now, and no, `HomeLocationKey` is not a foreign key to `Location`.

Comment: I have updated my original question with the two database calls solution that works but I don't want.

Comment: If the database schema is not maintained by migrations it's an option to tell EF that `HomeLocationCode` is a foreign key to `Location` even though in the database it isn't.